# Why am I getting a NoSuchElementException in this Java client/server setup?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, client-server, nosuchelementexception

I am making a java client/server socket program in netbeans that is supposed to accept a number and then return the square root/square the number.
It allows me to type in a number and then i get the following statement:
Exception found in Client: java.util.NoSuchElementException.

I am not sure why it is doing this, please help!

Here is my code for both classes:

Client:

```
package question1.clientserver;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        int number, temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1452);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Enter any number to be squared");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(number);
        temp = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception found in Client: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

and this is my server code

```
package question1.clientserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection, please stand by...");

        try {
            int number, temp;
            ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1452);
            Socket ss = s1.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection has been established");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
            number = sc.nextInt();

            temp = number * number;

            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());

            p.println(temp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Server while creating connection" + e);
        }

    }
}
}
}
```

if you have any ideas or suggestions please let me know!

stacktrace

```
run: Enter any number to be squared 
25 (which is what i type in for example) 
Exception found in Client: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
Build Successful (total time: 31 seconds)
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace please?

Comment: run:
Enter any number to be squared
25 (which is what i type in for example)
Exception found in Client: java.util.NoSuchElementException
(Build Successful (total time: 31 seconds)

Comment: It would make it easier for others to reproduce if you included your *complete* classes - with class declarations and imports...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - it "works" for me for a single client - but then the server goes into an exception loop because it's trying to reopen a socket when it hasn't closed the old one.

Comment: you are doing sc.nextint() multiple times that is causing  this issue.. can you place complete stacktrace.. so it will be easy for us to identify.

Comment: try with removing sc.nextInt() from client side.. not sure but you can have a try..

Comment: i have updated to show the full code and stacktrace if you would like to see @JonSkeet

Comment: have you tried with removing sc.nextint()? from client code

Comment: And how are you running it? If this is from within an IDE, have you tried running it from the command line instead?

Comment: @Vishal: How would you expect that to work? The point is to ask the user for a number...

Comment: @JonSkeet i am running it within the netbeans IDE, i will try the command line now

Comment: i am not sure which .nextInt() is causing issue.. that why i need to see complete stacktrace.. error he has mention occurs when no value found for .nextInt()

Comment: @Vishal: Well yes, but you don't fix the issue by just removing the required functionality...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you are correct.. but somewhere its going for extra .nextInt() if that is identified i think it should work.. i may be wrong.. just a wild guess that's the reason i am mentioning it in comments :P

Comment: @Vishal: There are two calls to `nextInt`, and the OP is trying to read two numbers (one from the user, one from the server). There's nothing "extra" here - removing either of those calls breaks the requirements. Besides, as I mentioned, it works for me - which suggests the problem may be with how the OP is running it (or the Netbeans console interaction). At that point I'd remove everything *except* the `sc.nextInt()` - I strongly suspect the server part is irrelevant here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clearing my doubt.. then could be issue with server side